# Unload Redshift data to S3 in parquet format

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to unload redshift data to S3, but it's unloading in CSV format. How can unload the Redshift table to S3 bucket in parquet format using Java?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

unload ('select * from lineitem')
to 's3://mybucket/lineitem/'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
PARQUET
PARTITION BY (l_shipdate);